# Get selected View inside ListView item

Tags: android, android-listview

My `ListView` item contains many views.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:weightSum="1"
              android:orientation="vertical">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_user_nick"
      <!-- other attributes --> />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_message_title"
      <!-- other attributes --> />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_date"
      <!-- other attributes --> />

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_user_icon"
      <!-- other attributes --> />
  </RelativeLayout>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/messages_listview_item_message_body"
    <!-- other attributes --> />

  <TextView
    <!-- attributes, no id needed --> />
</LinearLayout>
```

When the user select an item from the list, I'd like to get the specific `View` selected, that is the specific part of the item selected. For example, if the user select the `ImageView` inside the item, I'd like to get this specific `View`. Is there a method to do that?

The goal is to have different behaviors of the `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` based on the right `View` selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can Create a custom view or a Fragment as a Row. Then You can handle each Row's each view in your custom view or Fragment class.

Second option, in your custom adapter set on click listener for each View separately.

Comment: Can you provide some example on the first one? The second one is easiest, but I don't know if it is possible to have the same adapters for more than one view.

Comment: It seems that I can add a listener to each view separately, then add a listener to the item. In this way there is also a "default" behavior. Looks great!